# how can i list the file by creation date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, directory

I have ASP.NET (C#) 4.0.

My code is like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string searchPatternExpression)
{
    string path = @"D:\xxx\";
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption)
        .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file)))
        .OrderBy(file => file);
}
```

How can I order by file's creation date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thus you need to get file creation time, it's better to use `DirectoryInfo` to get `FileInfo`s instead of simple strings:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string searchPatternExpression)
{
    string path = @"D:\xxx\";
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return new DirectoryInfo(path)
        .EnumerateFiles("*", searchOption)
        .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(file.Name))
        .OrderBy(file => file.CreationTime)
        .Select(file => file.FullName); // return just names
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string searchPatternExpression)
{
    string path = @"D:\xxx\";
    SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
    return Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption)
        .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file)))
        .OrderBy(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime);
}
```

Comment: Need an additional .Select() to get back to a string. Fix that, and it will work... but it needs an extra disk access for each matching file.